# How do I optionally clean/access $scope variable from a $state view?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In my app the user enters some values on the first view ('tab.sim') then press button to calculate, the results are shown on other view ('tab.sim-result). Then the user has a options to go back and modify the values and recalculate, choosing this I don't want to clear the variables. But when the user chooses "simulator" from slide menu I need to clean all the values to allow him to do a totally new simulation.
But my app or always clear them all or let the values there no matter which button I click.
I think this is a scope issue but I do not know how to fix it. I tried {cache: false} then always clean the model variables. Without it the values are always there.

Thnaks in advance.

I have the following states in $stateProvider

```
.state('tab', {
  url: "/tab",
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
})

// Each tab has its own nav history stack:

.state('tab.sim', {
  url: '/sim',
  views: {
    'tab-sim': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-sim.html',
      controller: 'SimCtrl'
    }
  }
})
.state('tab.sim-result', {
  url: '/sim/result',
  views: {
    'tab-sim': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/sim-result.html',
      controller: 'SimResultCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: When you press the reset button then clear the values and then go back to the first page. Where exacly is the problem?

Comment: I'm going to edit my question and try to make me more clear, sorry. But my issue is when the user uses the menu option "simulator" he wants the app to force clear the simulation values @Michael ...

Comment: Where do you store your simulation values in the rootScope? In a chold scope an on which level? Or in a service? So if you select "simulator" clear the values and go to the tab.sim page or define a `resolve` object on the 'tab' state which will reset values if a $stateparam is set.... best is if you provide a plunker

Comment: I'm not using rootScope, It's child scope from menu. I'll try resolve. Can I get resolve values as parameters on my controller isn't it?

Comment: yes you can :-) you will have to inject the value also into the controller